# Magento : How to get category page URL keys for different store views?

Tags: php, magento, url

I'm trying to get the page URL Key for category pages for different store views. Basically I have 3 stores set up in my Magento installation. Now I want to implement hrefhang tags in my category pages. 
But I cannot access category URL keys of other store views when I'm in default store and vice versa.

I have category object which I get from,

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Solution, works well

```
/**
 * @var $store_id  - The numeric ID of the store view to get the URL from.
 * @var $store_url - Base URL of the store
 */

 $store_url   = Mage::app()->getStore($store_id)
                ->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK);

 $objcategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
 $categoryId  = $objcategory->getId();
 $caturlkey   = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->setStoreId($store_id)->load($categoryId)->getUrlKey();

 $altUrl      = $store_url.$caturlkey;
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the best way to get category URLs under a different store than the current one is to [make use of Magento’s `Mage_Core_Model_App_Emulation`](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8516/20131). Here’s an example of how you could do that:

```
/**
 * @var $categoryId - The numeric category ID you want to get the URL of.
 * @var $altStoreId - The numeric ID of the other store view to get the URL from.
 */
$env = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation')->startEnvironmentEmulation($altStoreId);
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$altUrl = $category->getUrl();
Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation')->stopEnvironmentEmulation($env);
```

Comment: Thanks Mate!, this is grate!!, unfortunately for some reason stopEnvironmentEmulation didn't work the way how it suppose to work, basically it gives me correct category URLs for each store, but it brakes the page (it stopped loading any categories). So I had to explore other ways to do this, and manage to came up with below answer.

Comment: It works, but it takes 20x more execution time than the Thanu's solution

Answer (score 0):

You can perform like this (should be less costly when an environment emulation):

```
$currentStore = Mage::app()->getStore();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::app()->getStore($yourAltStoreId));
$categoryLink = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($yourCategoryId)->getUrl();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($currentStore);
```